# Xamarin android xml (xmlns:app="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto") namespace does not work

Tags: c#, android, user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using xamarin android cheesebaron slide up panel for the main activity of my app. I want to change the collapsed height of the the grey panel (basically, make it so it would take about half the screen when first displayed). I have read that I should include xmlns:app="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" into the cheesebaron layout and use xml property app:collapsedHeight. However, none of the elements of the "app" xml namespace seem to be working. Any ideas why none of the "app" namespace properties do not work?

[image: This is how the main page looks, I want the grey panel to be bigger]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <cheesebaron.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    app:collapsedHeight="400dp"
    app:shadowHeight="40dp"
    app:slidingEnabled="false"
    app:fadeColor="FFDDAADD">
    <!-- Main content -->
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            />
    <!-- Sliding panel -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#444444"
            android:id="@+id/topBars"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </LinearLayout>

</cheesebaron.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Comment: The scheme should be `http`, not `https`.

Comment: Fml, thank you so much!